# Updating data in php(using html form) causes to update all row's data

Tags: php, html, sql-update

i want to edit my data in database called `simple_stall` with table `order_detail`...currently i have done a page that shows a list of data with `No` `Name` `Ordered_Item` `Quantity`. When user click the `No`, they'll be redirected to a new page that shows only the data of that he clicked.

Now, when user click on `Edit` button, they'll be redirected to a new page called `update_info.php`. Here is a form to change `Name` `Ordered_Item` and `Quantity`...but now when i click `update order` button, it will update all rows to be the data that user just put in...
What i want is to UPDATE only the data of that `No` that user click

this is the code
`order_detail.php`

```
<?php

include_once 'dbh.php';

$query = "SELECT * FROM order_detail"; //You don't need a ; like you do in SQL
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

echo "<table border = 1px>"; // start a table tag in the HTML

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{   
    $no = $row['No'];
    //Creates a loop to loop through results
    echo  "<tr><td style = 'width:30px;'>" . "<a href='view_more.php?no=$no'>" .$row['No'] . "</td>
               <td style = 'width:30%;'>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>
               <td style = 'width:30%;'>" . $row['Ordered_Item'] . "</td>
               <td>" . $row['Quantity'] . "</td></tr>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
}

echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML
echo "<button type='button'><a href='./index.php'>Back</a></button>";
```

`view_more.php`

```
if (isset($_GET['no']))
{
    include_once 'dbh.php';

    $no = $_GET['no'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM order_detail WHERE No = '$no'";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    echo "<table border = 1px>"; // start a table tag in the HTML

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {   

        //Creates a loop to loop through results
        echo  "<tr><td style = 'width:30px;'>" . $row['No'] . "</td>
                   <td style = 'width:30%;'>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>
                   <td style = 'width:30%;'>" . $row['Ordered_Item'] . "</td>
                   <td>" . $row['Quantity'] . "</td></tr>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
    }

    echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML

    echo "<button type='button'><a href='./update_info.php?no=$no'>Edit</a></button>";
    echo "<button type='button'><a href='#'>Delete</a></button>";
    echo "<button type='button'><a href='./order_detail.php'>Back</a></button>";

    mysqli_close($connection);
```

`update_info.php`

```
<form action="update_data.php" method="POST">
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="NewName" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="NewOrder" placeholder="Order">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="NewQuantity" placeholder="Quantity">
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" name="submit">Update Order</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

`update_data.php`

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    include_once 'dbh.php';

    $update = "UPDATE order_detail SET Name='$_POST[NewName]', Ordered_Item='$_POST[NewOrder]', Quantity='$_POST[NewQuantity]' ";

    if (mysqli_query($connection, $update))
    {
        header("Location: ./order_detail.php");
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        header("Location: ./order_detail.php?update=failed");
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your update doesn't have a WHERE clause, which will mean it will update every row in the table.

Comment: Also _never_ concatenate superglobals like `$_POST` directly into a query. This leaves you wide open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1). Use `filter_input` and prepared queries.

Answer (score 0):

*Add the Where clause and pass your id whose value you want to edit.Have a look at code below*

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        include_once 'dbh.php';

        $update = "UPDATE order_detail SET Name='$_POST[NewName]', Ordered_Item='$_POST[NewOrder]', Quantity='$_POST[NewQuantity]' WHERE No='$_GET[no]' ";

        if (mysqli_query($connection, $update))
        {
            header("Location: ./order_detail.php");
            exit();
        }
        else
        {
            header("Location: ./order_detail.php?update=failed");
            exit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: i got this error 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\simple_stall\update_data.php on line 7

Answer (score 0):

**Specify which order you want to update**

*look at the HTML and SQL I have change*

```
<form action="update_data.php" method="POST">
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="NewName" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="NewOrder" placeholder="Order">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="NewQuantity" placeholder="Quantity">
            </div>
            <div>





                <input type="hidden" name="No">
                <!-- Specify which order you want to update  -->




                <button type="submit" name="submit">Update Order</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

update_data.php

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    include_once 'dbh.php';


    $update = "UPDATE order_detail SET 
            Name='$_POST[NewName]', 
            Ordered_Item='$_POST[NewOrder]', 
            Quantity='$_POST[NewQuantity]' 
     WHERE No = {$_POST['No']} ";
   // add where clause in sql to specify which you want to update


    if (mysqli_query($connection, $update))
    {
        header("Location: ./order_detail.php");
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        header("Location: ./order_detail.php?update=failed");
        exit();
    }
}
```

Use prepared statement, it is safer

Answer (score 0):

add a hidden input with the value of $no to your update_info.php like this

```
<form action="update_data.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="no" value="<?php $_GET['no']; ?>" />
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="NewName" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="NewOrder" placeholder="Order">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="NewQuantity" placeholder="Quantity">
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit" name="submit">Update Order</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

and then change your sql query in update_data.php to be like this

```
"UPDATE order_detail SET Name='$_POST[NewName]', Ordered_Item='$_POST[NewOrder]', Quantity='$_POST[NewQuantity]' where = {$_POST['no']} ";
```